# CGContextSetShadow() - shadow direction reversed between iOS 3.0 and 4.0?

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics

I've been using `CGContextSetShadowWithColor()` in my Quartz drawing code on the iPhone to generate the "stomped in" look for text and other things (in `drawRect:` and `drawLayer:inContext:`).

Worked perfectly, but when running the exact same code against iOS 3.2 and now iOS 4.0 I noticed that the shadows are all in the opposite direction. E.g. in the following code I set a black shadow to be 1 pixel **above** the text, which gave it a "pressed in" look, and now this shadow is 1px **below** the text, giving it a standard shadow.

```
...
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.f, 1.f), 0.5f, shadowColor);
CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint(context, origin.x, origin.y, glyphs, length);
...
```

Now I don't know whether I am (or have been) doing something wrong or whether there has been a change to the handling of this setting. I haven't applied any transformation that would explain this to me, at least not knowingly. I've flipped the text matrix in one instance, but not in others and this behavior is consistent. Plus I wasn't able to find anything about this in the SDK Release Notes, so it looks like it's probably me. What might be the issue?

Comment: I've been having the same problem in my apps. I'd notice if my graphics were drawing upside down, so I know it's not some weirdness with the transform matrix. OS bug seems like the only explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems to be either a bug or intentional by Apple; either way in order to solve this I'm now using a `UIView` category. I set the shadow Y direction as it should be on iOS 3.2+, but as long as I'm supporting iOS < 3.2 I'll be using the following class method to multiply the direction either by 1 or -1, as needed by the device:

```
...
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.f, [UIView shadowVerticalMultiplier] * -1.f), 0.5f, textShadowColor);
...
```

Here's the category:

```
@interface UIView (shadowBug) 

+ (NSInteger) shadowVerticalMultiplier;    

@end


@implementation UIView (shadowBug)

+ (NSInteger) shadowVerticalMultiplier
{
    static NSInteger shadowVerticalMultiplier = 0;
    if (0 == shadowVerticalMultiplier) {
        CGFloat systemVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
        shadowVerticalMultiplier = (systemVersion < 3.2f) ? -1 : 1;
    }

    return shadowVerticalMultiplier;
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug they didn't get around to fixing, it seems. :)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 4.0 has this same change in behavior (I found my way here by searching on `CGContextSetShadow` while updating my iPhone app for 4.0). So, apparently `CGContextSetShadow` behaves one way if you link against iPhone OS 3.1.3 and before, and a different way if you link against iPhone OS 3.2 or later.

Comment: Exactly. Good thing is you can simply check if the current device runs < 3.2 and act accordingly, as I did in my category, so at least this is consistent.

Comment: It seems even if you link against an older SDK the reversal happens – see the Facebook App's reversed shadows!